# make radio buttons behave like checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see examples all over the internet about how to make checkboxes act like radio buttons, but is it possible to make a group of radio buttons acts like checkboxes (meaning multiple selections and deselections) with jquery? Let me know

Thank you

Comment: if you want select only one at a time then assign a name else set multiple radio name

Comment: The only question that come in my mind is: why?

Comment: I think reverse is possible in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of radio buttons is to force a "one selection only" group of inputs.

I think what you need is how to style checkboxes to look like radio buttons. This isn't recommended either, as users can find it counter-intuitive when browser chrome gets overridden on a site. But if you're set on having what appear to be radio buttons but with checkboxes functionality, it would be the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could give each radio button a different name to select more than one at a time and you could use JS to add a click event listener that will see if the box is already checked when it's clicked and if so, uncheck it.

Try it out yourself and if you have trouble, post what you've tried and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Looks like I cannot deselect a radio button once it is selected

Comment: @user765368 — Sounds like you failed to follow the instruction in this part of the answer: you could use JS to add a click event listener that will see if the box is already checked when it's clicked and if so, uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function()
{
  var previousValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');
  var name = $(this).attr('name');

  if (previousValue == 'checked')
  {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('previousValue', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("input[name="+name+"]:radio").attr('previousValue', false);
    $(this).attr('previousValue', 'checked');
  }
});
```